# How to get variable value in JSON by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have converted my .xml code to .json

For xml I am using something like this:

```
var stage = xml.getElementsByTagName("stage" + game.current_stage)[0];
```

How can you do that in json?
I want something like this:

```
var stage = json."stage"+ game.current_stage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the zero index for the JSON, and the correct syntax is:

```
var stage = json["stage" + game.current_stage][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question:

```
var stage = json["stage"+ game.current_stage];
```

Comment: Thanks and how can I set this in an variable:
"stage_startposition" : [ {"x":0}, {"y":0} ],

Answer (score 0):

```
var stage = json["stage" + game.current_stage];
```

Answer (score 0):

would you like to read by using Javascript or what?

Then below code helps. Please try with that

```
var stage = JSON.parse(json)["stage"+ game.current_stage];
```